# How to dynamically add values in a 2D array?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with 2D arrays. what I want, is to dynamically add elements in specific columns of my 2D array named `symboltable2`.
I have been doing it as;

result is another 1D array in which there are certain words:

```
string[,] symboltable2 = new string[,];

if (result.Contains("int")) {
    for (int todynamic = 0; todynamic < result.GetLength(0); todynamic++) {
        symboltable2[todynamic, 6] = "int";
    }
    for (int sym2 = 0; i < symboltable1.GetLength(0); sym2++) {
        f4.listBox6.Items.Add(symboltable1[sym2, 5]); // To show if the values are added or not
    }
}
```

but the code above isn't giving me any results... kindly help :(

Comment: `string[,] symboltable2= new string[,]` won't even compile: Array creation must have array size or array initializer

Comment: so wot is the proper way to declare it?

Comment: as i hav to keep my symboltable2 public

Answer (score 2):

while implementing arrays you need to give the array's dimension i.e.

```
string[,] sa = new string[5,15];
```

or

```
string[,] sa = new string[listString1.Count, listString2.Count]
```

about adding / changing elements to 2D array.. as a simple string array example :

```
sa[0, 1] = "a";
sa[0, 2] = "b";
sa[1, 0] = "Istanbul / Turkey";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the size of the array. And to have it public I would use a property and initialize your array in the class constructor like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string[,] symboltable2 { get; set; } 

    public MyClass()
    {
        symboltable2 = new string[10,10];
    }

            // ...
```

Comment: +1. If possible define it as `public string[,] SymbolTable2 { get; private set; }` using a private setter.

Comment: This will just the same in WinForms. Classes are classes and fields are fields.